# Password decryption not supported on .NET Core for Windows?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package-restore

I recently converted a private NuGet repository to require authentication.

To build a project that uses that repository, I added the authentication to the local NuGet.Config with `NuGet Sources add -name [repo_name] -Source [source_url] -UserName [username] -Password [password]`.

I now get the following error when I try running `dotnet restore`:

> Password decryption is not supported on .NET Core for this platform. The following feed uses an encrypted password: 'nuget-sdet'. You can use a clear text password as a workaround.

I know that this isn't supported on linux, but I'm running this on Windows Server 2012 R2.

This *is* running on a very old version of .NET Core: `1.0.0-preview2-003121`.

Is password decryption supported on Windows for newer versions of .NET Core?

Or am I stuck between either storing the password in clear text or re-enabling anonymous access to the feed?

Comment: Did you try to add `--store-password-in-clear-text` option? It seems that you are using a nuget CLI, so it would be `-StorePasswordInClearText` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-sources#options)

Comment: I know that I can store it in clear text.  I am trying to figure out if I have any options besides clear text passwords and enabling anonymous access to the repository.

Comment: This happend to my out of nowhere after updating VS 2022 to version 17.1.0. I've created [a related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23989).

Comment: Thanks @UweKeim. It also happened after installing VS 2022. As per https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23498 I did a workaround by moving `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll` out of that folder.

Answer (score 12):

In non windows OS you should add the suffix of `--store-password-in-clear-text`
to your add command.

As specified in the **dotnet nuget add source** article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source)

> --store-password-in-clear-text

Enables storing portable package source credentials by disabling password encryption.

Comment: Why is this the recommended solution? Storing passwords in clear text seems like a security risk.

Comment: This can be acceptable depending on your use case. Like if this configuration is staying within your machine's local nuget.config. But it's true that you need to be careful not to check it in within your solution or otherwise disseminate it.

Comment: Note that nuget.config supports environment variables, so you don't actually need to store your actual clear text password in source control.  E.g. `<add key="cleartextpassword" value="%NUGET_PASSWORD% />`.  This will, of course, require all of your developers to configure an environment variable for `NUGET_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

I have just came across to this issue on VS for Mac. Answers here are not really enlightening and microsoft documentation is unclear. The name `--store-password-in-clear-text` sounds like you have to store your repository password. Actually you can simply use an access token instead of your username.
For example on Azure Devops, you go to right-upper corner your account icon as in the image and select "Personal access tokens"

[image]

Then create a new access token by giving the permission Packing read

[image]

Copy your newly created access token use the command below using from the VS menu `Tools->SDK Command Prompt`

```
    dotnet nuget add source https://myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json -n myFeed  
-u usernamenotimportant -p yourtokencomeshere --store-password-in-clear-text
```

This command will update your nuget.config file which is found on the path `~/.nuget/Nuget/Nuget.config` this path is important because this is the Nuget.Config file used and displayed by Nuget package manager in VS4Mac.

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) on the MS docu, other path there is the 2nd Nuget.Config  `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config` that is not displayed by the Package Manager, i think that it is still used by MsBuild but not displayed. it will probably still work but can cause confusion as the Package Manager doesn't show your nuget source and your private packages.

Last point is, dont use Nuget CLI to add the source which is similar command like below

```
 nuget add source https://myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json -name myFeed  
    -username usernamenotimportant -password yourtokencomeshere -StorePasswordInClearText
```

This command is updating the other Nuget.Config on the .config folder that wont be displayed by the VS for Mac.

So at the end only your Token is stored like below

```
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <myFeed>
        <add key="Username" value="myusername" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="mytokencomeshere" />
      </myFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
```